# Merge records and columns

Tags: sql, merge, sybase

Data from table A:

```
id desc
1  huba
1  blub
3  foo
4  bar
```

And I'd like to have

```
id desc
1  huba, blub
3  foo
4  bar
```

So records with the same id should be merged and the desc concatenated.
Unfortunately I can't use string or concat. I get an error if I try to use these functions.

Sybase Version:
Sybase version: Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.5/EBF 19902 SMP ESD#5.1/P/x86_64/Enterprise Linux/asear155/2594/64-bit/FBO/Wed Jun 6 01:20:27 2012

Comment: Sybase seems to have `MERGE` http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/commands89.htm Have you tried this?

Comment: No, and I can't find a simple example how to use it.

Comment: And it seems that it is only available since version 15.7? Ah and thanks for the downvote for whatever reason...

Comment: I tried:
`create table #target(id int, desc nvarchar(10))
merge into #target t
using (select * from A) s
on t.id = s.id
when matched then
update set t.desc = t.desc + s.desc
when not matched then
insert(id, desc) values(s.id, s.desc)`

But this gives me incorrect syntax near 'merge' , 's' and '='

Answer (score 0):

Sybase ASE does not have any functions similar to list(), group_concat(), etc.

While Sybase ASE does provide some XML support, it doesn't provide support for the 'for xml / path()' construct.

And while it's possible to create a funky workaround in ASE 16 (using a table @variable and a user-defined function) ... you're not running ASE 16.

Net result is that you'll need to write some sort of looping construct to accomplish what you want, eg, a cursor that loops through the rows in the table.

NOTE: I'd have to think about the 'merge' idea but since you're running ASE 15.5 and 'merge' isn't available until ASE 15.7 ... I'll put that idea on the back burner for now.

ps - OK, there **is** a single-query solution but it involves using Application Context Functions (ACFs) (eg, get_appcontext(), set_appcontext()); but that's a very, Very, VERY messy solution ...